# Switch displayed traces via plotly dropdown menu

Tags: r, dplyr, onclick, plotly, r-plotly

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to replicate this tutorial over here for my own data: https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/

I created some fake data and made 4 plots:

```
#load libraries 

library(plotly)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)


# create data

x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 731, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
y <- rnorm(731,10,10)
z <- rnorm(731,5,5)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
    
    df <- data.frame(x,y, z, date)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)



# plot 1 : time series

 aggregate = df %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(y))

ts_1 <- ggplot(aggregate) + geom_line(aes(x = month, y = mean, group = 1)) +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle("time series 1")

plot_1 = ggplotly(ts_1)



#plot 2 : box plot

plot_2 <- plot_ly(df, y = ~y, color = ~x, type = "box") %>% layout(title = "boxplot")



#plot 3, 4 : scatter plots

df_1 <- df[which(df$x == "A"),]
df_2 <- df[which(df$x == "B"),]


plot_3 <- plot_ly( data = df_1, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 3")

plot_4 <- plot_ly( data = df_2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 4")
```

Once these 4 plots have been created, I know how to save them together:

```
sub = subplot(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, nrows = 2)
#view result
sub
```

[image]

Now what I am trying to do, is have the user "toggle" (switch) between these graphs (as seen here: https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/)

In a previous post ([R: Switching Between Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141967/r-switching-between-graphs) ), I learned how to "glue" similar graphs together (e.g. 4 scatter plots). Now, I am trying to do so with different graphs (2 scatter plots, 1 time series and 1 box plot). I tried to adapt the code from the previous post to suit my example:

```
fig <- df %>% 
  add_trace(name = "A", plot_1) %>% 
  add_trace (name = "B" , df, y = ~y, color = ~x, type = "box") %>% layout(title = "boxplot")
  add_trace (name = "C" , data = df_1, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 3") %>%
  add_trace( name = "D", data = df_2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 4") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             y = 0.7,
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "A"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "B"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "C"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "D")))))
```

But this produces the following errors:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Error in add_data(p, data) : argument "p" is missing, with no default
```

Can someone please show me if it is possible to fix this problem? Instead of using the `"add_trace"` approach, is it somehow possible to individually call each plotly graph object by its name (e.g. `subplot(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, nrows = 2)`), "glue" all the graphs together, and then add a "toggle button" that lets the user switch between them?

(note: I need to be able to save the final result as a "html" file)

Thanks

Comment: `add_trace` expects a `plot_ly` object, not a `data.frame`, which explains the error you're encountering.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should take care about plots which add multiple traces (see `nTracesA` etc.)

Besides changing the trace visibility you'll need to seperate categorial and numerical data onto separate x and y-axes and manage their visibility, too (see `xaxis2`, `xaxis3`, `xaxis4` - this also works with a single y-axis but in this case the grid isn't displayed properly)

As [described in the docs](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/):

> The updatemenu method determines which plotly.js function will be used
> to modify the chart. There are 4 possible methods:

- "restyle": modify data or data attributes
- "relayout": modify layout attributes
- "update": modify data **and** layout attributes
- "animate": start or pause an animation (only available offline)

Accordingly the following, is using the **update method** (a lot of repition here - needs some cleanup, but I think it's better to understand this way):

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# create data
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:4],
            731,
            replace = TRUE,
            prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
y <- rnorm(731, 10, 10)
z <- rnorm(731, 5, 5)
date <- seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "day")

df <- data.frame(x, y, z, date)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)

nTracesA <- nTracesC <- nTracesD <- 1
nTracesB <- length(unique(df$x))

plotA <- plot_ly(data = df %>%
                   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
                   group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
                   summarise(mean = mean(y)),
                 type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~ month, y= ~ mean, name = "plotA", visible = TRUE, xaxis = "x", yaxis = "y")

plotAB <- add_trace(plotA, data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~ x, name = ~ paste0("plotB_", x), 
                    type = "box", xaxis = "x2", yaxis = "y2", visible = FALSE, inherit = FALSE)

plotABC <- add_trace(plotAB, data = df[which(df$x == "A"),], 
                     type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~ z, 
                     name = "plotC", xaxis = "x3", yaxis = "y3", visible = FALSE, inherit = FALSE)

plotABCD <- add_trace(plotABC, data = df[which(df$x == "B"),], x = ~ y, y = ~ z,
                      type = "scatter", mode = "markers", name = "plotD", xaxis = "x4", yaxis = "y4", visible = FALSE, inherit = FALSE)

fig <- layout(plotABCD, title = "Initial Title",
              xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1), visible = TRUE, type = "date"),
              xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
              xaxis3 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE), 
              xaxis4 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
              yaxis = list(title = "y"),
              yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
              yaxis3 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
              yaxis4 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
              updatemenus = list(
                list(
                  y = 0.7,
                  buttons = list(
                    list(label = "A",
                         method = "update",
                         args = list(list(name = paste0("new_trace_name_", 1:7), visible = unlist(Map(rep, x = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), each = c(nTracesA, nTracesB, nTracesC, nTracesD)))),
                                     list(title = "title A",
                                          xaxis = list(visible = TRUE),
                                          xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis3 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis4 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis = list(visible = TRUE),
                                          yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis3 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis4 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE)))
                    ),
                    list(label = "B",
                         method = "update",
                         args = list(list(visible = unlist(Map(rep, x = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), each = c(nTracesA, nTracesB, nTracesC, nTracesD)))),
                                     list(title = "title B",
                                          xaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = TRUE),
                                          xaxis3 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis4 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = TRUE),
                                          yaxis3 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis4 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE)))),
                    list(label = "C",
                         method = "update",
                         args = list(list(visible = unlist(Map(rep, x = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), each = c(nTracesA, nTracesB, nTracesC, nTracesD)))),
                                     list(title = "title C",
                                          xaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis3 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = TRUE),
                                          xaxis4 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis3 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = TRUE),
                                          yaxis4 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE)))),
                    list(label = "D",
                         method = "update",
                         args = list(list(visible = unlist(Map(rep, x = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), each = c(nTracesA, nTracesB, nTracesC, nTracesD)))),
                                     list(title = "title D",
                                          xaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis3 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = FALSE),
                                          xaxis4 = list(overlaying = "x", visible = TRUE),
                                          yaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis3 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = FALSE),
                                          yaxis4 = list(overlaying = "y", visible = TRUE))))
                  ))))

print(fig)

# htmlwidgets::saveWidget(partial_bundle(fig), file = "fig.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
# utils::browseURL("fig.html")
```

[image: result]

Some related info:
https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/
https://plotly.com/r/multiple-axes/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! is there any way to change the horizontal axis for the scatter plots from here: https://imgur.com/a/I35cLGi to https://imgur.com/a/1wjwTjK? thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess from the documentation but there is no add_data() call so maybe try this for your first line:

```
fig <- plot_ly() %>% add_data(df) %>%
```

See docs example:

```
plot_ly() %>% add_data(economics) %>% add_trace(x = ~date, y = ~pce)
```

Comment: I just tried this and got the following error: Error in add_data(p, data) : argument "p" is missing, with no default .... do you know what could be causing this error? thanks

Answer (score 0):

A user on the Rstudio community forum provided an answer : https://community.rstudio.com/t/gluing-graphs-together-switch-toggle-between-graphs-in-r-plotly/95891/3

I am still trying to figure out how to format the axis - maybe someone could take a look at this?

```
#load libraries 

library(plotly)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)


# create data

x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 731, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
y <- rnorm(731,10,10)
z <- rnorm(731,5,5)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
    
    df <- data.frame(x,y, z, date)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)



# plot 1 : time series

 aggregate = df %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(y))

ts_1 <- ggplot(aggregate) + geom_line(aes(x = month, y = mean, group = 1)) +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle("time series 1")

plot_1 = ggplotly(ts_1)



#plot 2 : box plot

plot_2 <- plot_ly(df, y = ~y, color = ~x, type = "box") %>% layout(title = "boxplot")



#plot 3, 4 : scatter plots

df_1 <- df[which(df$x == "A"),]
df_2 <- df[which(df$x == "B"),]


plot_3 <- plot_ly( data = df_1, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 3")

plot_4 <- plot_ly( data = df_2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 4")


fig = plot_ly()
fig = fig %>% add_trace(data = df %>%
                          mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
                          group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
                          summarise( mean = mean(y)), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~month, y= ~mean,
                        name = "timeseries")
fig = fig %>%  add_trace(data = df[which(df$x == "A"),], y = ~y, color = ~x, 
                         type = "box", name = "boxplot") 
fig = fig %>%  add_trace( data = df[which(df$x == "B"),], 
                          type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z, 
                          name= "graph2")
fig = fig %>%  add_trace(data = df[which(df$x == "A"),], y = ~y, color = ~x, 
                         type = "box", name = "boxplot2") 


fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
               yaxis = list(title = "y"),
               updatemenus = list(
                 list(
                   y = 0.7,
                   buttons = list(
                     list(method = "restyle",
                          args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                          label = "A"),
                     list(method = "restyle",
                          args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                          label = "B"),
                     list(method = "restyle",
                          args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                          label = "C"),
                     list(method = "restyle",
                          args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                          label = "D")))))
```