# R Error: First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, data-manipulation, interactive

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/

I tried to create my own data and run the same procedure:

```
library(plotly)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)


# create data

x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 731, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
y <- rnorm(731,10,10)
z <- rnorm(731,5,5)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
    
    df <- data.frame(x,y, z, date)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)


#create plot
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~y, z = ~z )
fig <- fig %>%  plot_ly(df, y = ~y, color = ~x, type = "box")
fig <- fig %>%  plot_ly( data = df, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
        list(
            y = 0.8,
            buttons = list(
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("line.color", "blue"),
                     label = "Blue"),
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("line.color", "red"),
                     label = "Red")))
    )
)

fig
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error: First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.
```

I tried to add another plot to this "fig"

```
# time series plot
 aggregate = df %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(y))

ts_1 <- ggplot(aggregate) + geom_line(aes(x = month, y = mean, group = 1)) +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + ggtitle("time series 1")

plot_1 = ggplotly(ts_1)

fig <- fig %>%  plot_1
```

But this also does not work.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which plot from that page you are trying to implement. Here is a way to implement first 2 of them.

Data :

```
library(plotly)
x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 731, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
y <- rnorm(731,10,10)
z <- rnorm(731,5,5)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

df <- data.frame(x,y, z, date)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)
```

Simple Dropdown :

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~y, y = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(marker = list(line = list(color = "black", width = 1)))
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Drop down menus - Plot type",
  xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
  yaxis = list(title = "y"),
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("type", "scatter"),
             label = "Scatter"),
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("type", "histogram2d"),
             label = "2D Histogram")))
  ))

fig
```

[image]

For the 2nd plot :

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date)
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~y, name = "A")
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~z, name = "B", visible = F)
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
  xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
  yaxis = list(title = "y"),
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("line.color", "blue"),
             label = "Blue"),
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("line.color", "red"),
             label = "Red")))
  )
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah for your help! I am trying to combine the first picture you posted and the second picture you posted into a single plotly object. I am trying to make a plotly object in which you can view different types of plots together (e.g. scatterplot, time series, box plot, etc.). This question was in reference to another question that I had posted earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic . Do you know if it is possible to do this? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Ins't the first picture what you want then? It has scatterplot and 2D histogram in it. You just need to add more plots in it.

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure how to add more plots. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic in this question here, i know how to use the plotly::subplot() command to put multiple graphs on the same page  .... but i dont know how to "toggle" the graphs like in this example. Do you have any idea how to do this? I am still trying to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: So that is a different question which is being handled in that post, right?

Comment: The error produced in this question is a different error

Comment: I thought this question is different than the other question. So I am not sure what you are looking for in this question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to combine the scatter plot with the time series plot into a single figure? So that,  when you click on the button on the left, the first option is a scatterplot and the second is the time series?

Comment: Both the plots have different axes so I am not sure if we can combine them.

Comment: (I just placed a bounty on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic)

Comment: I am struggling to update the titles, if you have time, can you please take a look at this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201634/r-titles-on-graphs-not-updating thank you