# using list of plots as arguments in plotly dropdown

Tags: r, r-plotly

Is it possible to select a plot from a list using `plotly` dropdown? For example if I create the list of plots below how would I create a dropdown to pick each by name and display? Thanks

```
library(plotly)
fig_1 <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "histogram")


x = c("Apples","Apples","Apples","Oranges", "Bananas")
y = c("5","10","3","10","5")

fig_2 <- plot_ly(y=y, x=x, histfunc='sum', type = "histogram")
fig_2 <- fig_2 %>% layout(yaxis=list(type='linear'))


fig_3 <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)

list_of_plots=list(hist=fig_1,bar=fig_2,scatter=fig_3)
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/switch-displayed-traces-via-plotly-dropdown-menu/66205810#66205810) might be of interest.